# Heroku gui cloud

Tags: user-interface, heroku, cloud

is there any app that support visual GUi interface for heroku cloud. I cant find all over the net...

the gitbush (command system) is so hard to work ...

So if you have any solution for this please send me. I need this for creating an facebook realtime game

Comment: What exactly are you after? A GUI for Git, or something that understands the (very simple) Heroku API/CLI?

Comment: both... so is there a gui for git

Comment: the best gui for gitbush to work with heroku cloud... somethnig like cpanel on shared hosting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's plenty of GUIs for Git ranging from [GitHub for Mac](http://mac.github.com/), [Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/), [Gitx](http://gitx.frim.nl/) and so on.

Heroku wise there's only one I know of - [nezumi](http://nezumiapp.com/#/iphone) for iPhone.  Generally speaking there's no Heroku GUIs because the CLI is so darn simple.

All of the above are assuming you're on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:
1. create an app with heroku webpage, get its Git URL: git@heroku.com:your-app-name.git
2. use Gitbox (bought from mac app store) to upload (adding your local and set the remote giturl)

Answer (score 0):

### Github For Windows

You can use [GitHub for Windows](https://windows.github.com) if you don't like the `terminal` / `shell` / `cmd.exe`